# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "WORKING" not found; SQL statement

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, h2

I'm trying to test my app using h2 in memory database first time in my life and I faced with some problem. When I try to start test it shows me such error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "WORKING" not found; SQL statement
```

I tried to find the answer on the internet and found that instead of this recording:

```
jdbc:h2:file:jdbc:h2:mem:db;SCHEMA=working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

I can use this:

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

But it didn't fix this error.

Here's my application.properties config for tests:

```ini
#Hibernate
spring.datasource.url=${spring.flyway.url}
spring.datasource.username=${spring.flyway.user}
spring.datasource.password=${spring.flyway.password}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=debug
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.devtools.restart.enabled = false

#flyway
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;SCHEMA=working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.flyway.user=sa
spring.flyway.password=sa
#spring.flyway.schemas=working
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

Here's my test:

**UserServiceTest.java**

```java
@DataJpaTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @AfterEach
    public void deleteDb() {
        List<UserEntity> users = userRepo.findAll();
        userRepo.deleteAll(users);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testUserAdding() {
        List<UserAddModel> addModels = getUserAddModels();
        addModels.forEach(m -> isUserGetModelValid(m, userService.addUser(m)));
        addModels = getInvalidUserAddModels();
        addModels.forEach(m -> isUserGetModelValid(m, userService.addUser(m)));
    }


    private List<UserAddModel> getUserAddModels() {
        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new UserAddModel(
                        "Alla",
                        "Pugacheva",
                        null,
                        "+19772395747",
                        null,
                        "AbobaAbobaAboba"
                ),
                new UserAddModel(
                        "Andrey",
                        "Magnolin",
                        "FiftithEnumed",
                        "+19164167722",
                        null,
                        "Fi123sdamJfw+"
                ),
                new UserAddModel(
                        "Andy",
                        "Balk",
                        "Isuch",
                        "+112486759123",
                        "IBiB@Basas",
                        "IBiB@Basas"
                )
        ));

    }

    private void isUserGetModelValid(UserAddModel userAddModel, UserGetModel userGetModel) {
        Assertions.assertAll(
                () -> Assertions.assertNotNull(userGetModel.getId()),
                () -> Assertions.assertEquals(userAddModel.getFirstName(), userGetModel.getFirstName()),
                () -> Assertions.assertEquals(userAddModel.getLastName(), userGetModel.getLastName()),
                () -> Assertions.assertEquals(userAddModel.getPatronymic(), userGetModel.getPatronymic()),
                () -> Assertions.assertEquals(userAddModel.getEmail(), userGetModel.getEmail()),
                () -> Assertions.assertEquals(userAddModel.getPhoneNumber(), userGetModel.getPhoneNumber())
        );
    }

    private List<UserAddModel> getInvalidUserAddModels() {
        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new UserAddModel(
                  "FFRoasd*!TИffВ]\\\"!@}#{$yfdf4?/\\\\f\\\\%^}12н4#)([",
                  "Zsda_q*!fjIJF]\\\"!@}#{$yfdf4?/\\\\f\\\\%^}12н4#)([",
                  "ZHansda-*!ffjja@]\\\"!@}#{$yfdf4?/\\\\f\\\\%^}12н4#)([",
                        "ff@.google.com",
                        "HAHAH +15026812036749(643)40-2-75 go0odLuck",
                        "Э?"
                ),
                new UserAddModel(
                        "Alla",
                        "Pugacheva",
                        null,
                        "sb@.google.com",
                        null,
                        "AbobaAbobaAboba"
                ),
                new UserAddModel(
                        "Andrei",
                        "Balk",
                        "Iv",
                        "+112486759123",
                        "outlook.com",
                        "IlkbB@Ilkbib"
                ),
                new UserAddModel(
                        "Andy",
                        "Balcony",
                        "IVconf",
                        "+112486759123",
                        "mmm@google.com",
                        "AAA?"
                )
            )
        );
    }

    @Nested
    private class UserNestedTests {

    }
}
```

Here's my migration sql file

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    patronymic varchar(512),
    phone_number varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email varchar(64) UNIQUE,
    password varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    state varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Here's my **UserEntity.java** class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "working")
@Getter @Setter
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String patronymic;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String state;

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    public UserEntity(String firstName, String lastName, String patronymic, String phoneNumber, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static UserEntity toModel(UserAddModel userAddModel) {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.map(userAddModel, user);
        user.state = StateConstantsConfig.STUDENT;
        return user;
    }
}
```

So what can be the problem? If you know, please, tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html?highlight=schema&search=schema#set_schema), for settings the SCHEMA you need to execute the command `SET SCHEMA <name>`. In your example, it will look like this:

- `jdbc:h2:mem:db;SET SCHEMA working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

But H2 knows nothing about the schema `working`. It only knows about the default schema `PUBLIC`. To help it, you need to create this schema the way you tried. And the full URL will look like this:

- `jdbc:h2:mem:db;INIT=create schema if not exists working\;SET SCHEMA working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

Note that the backslash `\` is required.

But if you don't need any schema, you won't be able to use it. You can just name the database `working` like this:

- `spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

Comment: Database name and schema name are not related to each other in H2.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I'll correct my answer. @EvgenijRyazanov

Comment: @MaksimEliseev Thank you for answering but unfortunately I still get this error even after replacing my url with two of our proposed variants :/

Comment: I just update my answer with some corrections @Cross Check it again

Comment: Alright, thanks, I got how does it work. But when I create schema and set it in url(with backslash), I get url error that says **URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]" but is "jdbc:h2:mem:db"**

Comment: Can you provide the resulting URL? @Cross

Comment: @MaksimEliseev Yes, sure, here it is ```jdbc:h2:mem:db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS working\;SET SCHEMA working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1```

Comment: It's very strange, but your URL works fine in my environment. Which version of Spring are you using? Can you try to double the backslash? @Cross

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I'm currently using Spring boot 3.1.2. Well, if I try to double the slash it throws me **Schema "WORKING" not found error** again :/ Here's my url with double slash ```jdbc:h2:mem:db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS working\\;SET SCHEMA working;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1```

Comment: Is the exception related to Spring or Flyway? @Cross

Comment: @MaksimEliseev No, it looks like it is a jdbc exception: ```org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    drop table if exists working.users cascade " via JDBC
[Schema "WORKING" not found;]  Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "WORKING" not found; SQL statement```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254745/discussion-between-maksim-eliseev-and-cross).